# How to align the suggestion list based on textbox box position

Tags: css, position, positioning

I have div in that there is a textbox.before textbox, there is some text.

on keyup of the textbox, list suggestions are popping up. What I want is this suggestion list should be based on the position of the textbox. like if the text is extreme right then the list should pop up just below that textbox not the way its currently popping up.

Here is code snippet of it

```js
function getval()
{

  textval = document.getElementById("srval").value;
  if(textval.length>0)
  {
      document.getElementById("list").style.display="block";
  }
  else
  {
        document.getElementById("list").style.display="none";     
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div style="border:1px red solid;width:250px;height:20px">
 Coffeee Teat MIlk
   <input type="text" id="srval" onkeyup="getval()" style="position:absolute">
    <ul style="display:none;position:relative;top:5px" id="list">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
 </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your list has `position: relative` on it -- it will **already** be relative to the location of the input. And the list currently shows up directly below the textbox, which is what you say you want. What about the current display is not working the way you would like?

Comment: Ya but while list is popping up its on left instead just below to input thats the issue @ObsidianAge

Comment: It's still **very unclear** what you're looking for, but perhaps you just want `left: 100px` on `#list`.

Comment: do you want to create auto compelete textbox?

Comment: yes @לבנימלכה but it should goes just below textbox not like what currently there

Comment: if I give 100px to list it will be hardcoded with 100px and if in future length of text which is written before textbox is increased then that 100px will not adjust automatically, I want that list which is poping up always should go below textbox. @ObsidianAge

Comment: there is nicer way to create auto complete see here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks @לבנימלכה actually I need to implement this using react. For understanding how logic should work I am making this in js

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
function getval() {

  textval = document.getElementById("srval").value;
  if (textval.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("list").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px
}

input {
  position: absolute
}

#list {
  display: none;
}

#list,
#list li {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <form>
    <label style="border:1px red solid;width:250px;height:20px">
 Coffeee Teat Milk</label>
    <input type="text" id="srval" onkeyup="getval()" style="">
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>


  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Horacio Coronel. I will look to implement in this way as well. At the end of day I willl be converting this code to react, as I need to implement this in react.For understanding logic I am making in JS